# Returning proper values using CONCAT function

Tags: google-bigquery

Okay, so say I'm using the CONCAT function, right?

So I have a date in a field called start_date. It looks like 2016-02-07.

Next, I subqueried that to do MONTH(start_date) AS start_month and YEAR(start_date) as start_year. Obviously, start_month would return 02 and start_year returns 2016.

Now lets say I wanted to combine those two so it says 02/2016. If I simply do:

CONCAT('start_month', '/', 'start_year') it returns start_month/start_year and if I do CONCAT(start_month, '/', start_year) it returns Error: CONCAT: The 1st argument has type int64 but expected type string or bytes.

So what am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? Additionally, is there an easy way I can convert the numerical months to their actual names (i.e. 02 becomes February)? If there isn't an easy way, its not a huge deal.

Answer (score 2):

> from question: Obviously, start_month would return 02 and start_year
>   returns 2016.

Nope - they will return 2 and 2016 respectivelly and as integers not as strings - see more on [MONTH()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#month) and/or [Date and time functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions)

So you should cast month and year values to [STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#castingfunctions)

For example,
CONCAT(STRING(start_month), '/', STRING(start_year))

> The better way to do this is as below

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC('2016-02-07', "%m-%Y")
```

see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#strftime_utc_usec) for more details

> is there an easy way I can convert the numerical months to their
>   actual names (i.e. 02 becomes February)?

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC('2016-02-07', "%B")
```